# How to tilt a rigid LCD Wall Mount?

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, installation, display

I recently bought a Wall Mount for my 24" LCD TV, it is just a few feet above my workspace desktop, but I need it to be a little bit tilted because I'm quite near the screen. I can't afford another wall-mount device, any ideas ?

Description of the mount: http://bit.ly/cfyrEG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a fixed angle is required, you could use some spacers on the top most mounting holes, you'll want to make sure that you have long enough screws though.  Be very sure that it's still sturdy and do this at your own risk.  You can use washer or some other style of spacer, just increase the bolt length by the same amount that the spacers are.

Answer (score 0):

You bought the wrong kind of wall-mount. Take the one you got back and exchange it for an ST650, LT25, or another tilting wall mount.